# How performance of Macbook Air 13" mid-2011 battery from iFixit compares to the original one?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, repair, third-party, energy

Please share your performance of the replacement [battery as sold by iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Store/Parts/MacBook-Air-13-Inch-Mid-2011-Mid-2012-Battery/IF188-070-1) (I'm interested in the *New* one, not *B-Stock*) as compared to the original battery from Apple for Macbook Air 13" mid-2011 (particularly, an i7 processor modification)?

Does it wear out faster? How long does it hold after 1 year+ of frequent (or, ideally, heavy) use? How many charge cycles does the iFixit version have, according to specs?

**Update:** I already contacted iFixit sales, but [their answers were not satisfactory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/131777/54644).

Comment: The page you link to sells B-Stock and new parts. Which are you shopping for? (also - hardware shopping is off topic, but asking how to compare options and getting an opinion is allowed.) A couple of edits should make this less about shopping if you want to clarify what information you can't get by asking the vendor.

Comment: @bmike Clarified that I'm asking about New one. Any other edits required? Otherwise, I don't see how this contradicts current "What topics can I ask about here?", and I [asked](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/question-allowed-here-buying-a-battery-replacement-for-macbook-air-if-apple-doe#comment3641_1881) before posting a [more general question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113804/most-robust-and-lasting-replacement-battery-for-macbook-air-2011?lq=1) (which this question is clearly a subset of).

Comment: Thanks - that clarification is good. Since you edited it, the question is in a queue to be reopened by the community moderators. It might need no further changes to get reopened. I would cast a reopen vote myself if you clarified if you were either looking for people to report their usage of this part or if you asked how to measure things. Most of your three questions would be best answered buy asking the vendor what their warranty is and how long it will hold up. Again, it's quite opinion based and too broad for my taste with the multiple questions at the end.

Comment: I asked the vendor, and the answers were not satisfactory, so I need real-customer experiences. Any suggestions how can I make the question less broad? Yes, I'm looking to report their usage experience--how can I clarify that? "If you asked how to measure things" -- didn't mean that, please suggest how to make the question clear on that.

Comment: Edit that in - showing your research helps others in addition to focusing what specifically you want.

Comment: @bmike I added that info as an [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/131777/54644) for the more general question], as it seem much more relevant there. But I just added an update here as well--does it look better now?